# react native packager building bundle loop

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, bundler

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 78ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 80ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 79ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 83ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 66ms.
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 67ms.
```

the project is not in any synced cloud folder, what can cause this?

- it happens only on ios (both simulator and device). the android works just fine.

Comment: yes a few times

Comment: try expo start -c

Answer (score 0):

I had an "iOS Bundling complete" loop.
It was because I forgot about another project which ran at that moment.

I stopped my app backend (Java Spring-Boot + Rancher Desktop) and front-end (React App). After that, my React Native started working as expected.